# Notifications from Nagios4 to Telegram

Tags: nagios

Can't get alerts from my nagios.
Server on Debian. Installed telegram-cli from github.com/vysheng/tg

Configuration files of Nagios4.

commands.cfg:

```
#'notify-service-by-tg' command definition
define command{
        command_name    notify-service-by-tg
        command_line    /home/nagios/tg/bin/telegram-cli -WR -U root -D -e 'msg $_CONTACTTG$ $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$ Host : $HOSTNAME$ - Service : $SERVIC$
}
#'notify-host-by-tg' command definition
define command{
        command_name    notify-host-by-tg
        command_line    /home/nagios/tg/bin/telegram-cli -WR -U root -D -e 'msg $_CONTACTTG$  "$NOTIFICATIONTYPE$ Host : $HOSTNAME$ is $HOSTSTATE$ @ $
}
```

contacts.cfg:

```
define contact{

contact_name nagiosadmin;
use generic-contact;
alias Nagios Admin;
service_notification_period 24x7;
host_notification_period 24x7;
service_notification_options w,u,c,r,f,s;
email nagios@localhost;
_tg Anton_T;
service_notification_commands notify-service-by-tg;
host_notification_commands notify-host-by-tg;

}
define contactgroup{

contactgroup_name       admins
alias                   Nagios Administrators
members                 nagiosadmin

       }
```

Having this error from nginx:

```
2015/12/31 20:56:47 [info] 512#0: *299 client closed connection while waiting for request, client: 1*8.*.*.*, server: 0.0.0.0:800
```

help, plz!

Comment: show a manual run. also, it looks like your "command_line" lines got truncated

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

You need to activate Telegram code as user nagios.

```
su - nagios

/home/nagios/tg/bin/telegram-cli -k /home/nagios/tg/tg-server.pub
```

and enter the code send to you as sms